# Parameters to Spring Boot Applciation War on JBOSS WEB

Tags: maven, tomcat, spring-boot, build, jboss-web

I have a application Spring Boot that I was using the embeded tomcat, but now I have to migrate it to JBOSS WEB SERVER.

I changed my application packaging to war, instead of using jar, and put the. But when I was using the jar to start the application I was passing parameters in the command line using "-Dproperty".

How can I do that now I am using Jboss Web (tomcat)?

Command Line I used to run:

```
java -jar -dzookeeper.connection.string=localhost:8080 project.jar
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Add that property tp application.properties.